# How do I implement a bootstrap file to html correctly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I want to learn bootstrap and therefore want to try it out myself.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-responsive.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4"><h1>Test1</h1></div>
        <div class="span4"><h1>Test2</h1></div>
        <div class="span4"><h1>Test3</h1></div>
    </div>

    <p> Hi </p>


<script src="jquery-2.1.3.webarchive"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

All the linked files are in the same folder as the `index.html` file. When I open the index.html it's not how I expected it to be. It's just simple html without any bootstrap.

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">

</head>
<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Console doesn't say anything and it's still not working.

EDIT2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">

    <style>
    .container {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .borders {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    <script> console.log("Hi")</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">           
            <div class="borders col-xs-6"></div>
                <h1>EXTRA SMALL GRID 1</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="borders col-xs-6"></div>
                <h1>EXTRA SMALL GRID 2</h1>
            </div>
        </div><!--ROW-->

        <div class="row">           
            <div class="borders col-sm-6"></div>
                <h1>SMALL GRID 3</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="borders col-sm-6"></div>
                <h1>SMALL GRID 4</h1>
            </div>
        </div><!--ROW-->

        <div class="row">           
            <div class="borders col-md-6"></div>
                <h1>MEDIUM GRID 5</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="borders col-md-6"></div>
                <h1>MEDIUM GRID 6</h1>
            </div>
        </div><!--ROW-->

        <div class="row">           
            <div class="borders col-lg-6"></div>
                <h1>LARGE GRID 7</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="borders col-lg-6"></div>
                <h1>LARGE GRID 8</h1>
            </div>
        </div><!--ROW-->

    </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `When I open the index.html it's not how I expected it to be. `And when you open your console???

Comment: try moving the `<script>`s to the head part..

Comment: you'll have to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` too for thr bootstrap to work..try it..

Comment: It's a good start to download the bootstrap version of html5boilerplate and start working there. (http://html5boilerplate.com/ no relationship no publicity, i think is a good start point to play locally).

Comment: @Lal why would moving scripts to the head change anything? It's a good practice to load them at end of body

Comment: just for debugging @charlietfl..just wanted to see if anything changes..

Comment: How do I post code again in the comments section?

Comment: @KevinN. try out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you download files from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download ?
You need to add bootstap.css OR the min css file version.

I Replaced css, jquery and js files with CDN links, since I am not sure what files you are using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>          
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>

    <div class="span4"><h1>Test1</h1></div>
    <div class="span4"><h1>Test2</h1></div>
    <div class="span4"><h1>Test3</h1></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><h1>Test1</h1></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><h1>Test2</h1></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><h1>Test3</h1></div>
</div>

<p> Hi </p>

</div>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

You may try to replace each cdn link one by one with your files and see where there problem is. 
Good Luck !

Comment: you have to read question properly **It's just simple html without any bootstrap.**

Comment: @Kevin N. Your [Edit] has no items in <body>...</body> to get displayed.  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mseo6a2b/).

Comment: I know but even if I put some divs in it with some bootstrap classes, it won't work-

Comment: @neoLok I tried your code. The buttons are fine but the grid is the thing that never works! :0 So that means bootstrap is implemented but the grid doesn't want to work :( What should I do now?
http://i.imgur.com/RCgWbtT.png

Comment: ok I think I got it now :). **spanX** ( span1, span2 etc) has been depreciated in bootstrap3 versions. To set up your grid layout you need to use  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><h1>Test1</h1></div>. Note lg/mg/sm/xs are for screen sizes... check documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. Here is a demo : [jsfidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/neolok/v6vyz7Lp/1/)

Comment: @KevinN. Edited html in my answer. Please try it again. Now you should see Test1 Test2 Test3 aligned horizontally.

Comment: Wow thanks this is really weird. I tried that yesterday already but it didn't work. Edited html in my answer. Thank You!

Comment: **DOWNVOTE** why? who? Kevin clearly mentioned he wanted to learn bootstrap and there is something wrong with Html that he can't see bootstrap (later he was more specific in pointing out Bootstrap's Grid Layout). I dont think Kevin changed question, he became more specific eventually. Happens when you pick new technology. Please explain _downvotes_ for me ? I was trying to help. Solution can be simple as long as it extends help to a fellow in community.

Comment: My question has been downvoted, too. I'm just a newbie so if only someone told me if I shouldn't be editing the question to specify myself where to do it instead

Comment: @KevinN. Yeah I agree with you. You probably shouldn't have got down voted. I don't think you changed your question as claimed by another user. For which I think he _wrongly_ downvoted you. Although I feel you could have done a bit more research and thought it through before posting your question. Probably you learned it now and be careful in future. I upvoted for you. Good Luck !

Comment: In some videos on Youtube "span4" was being used so I tried that but didn't work. I actually googled it, if that counts as research. :) Thanks, upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in question *All the linked files are in the same folder as the index.html file. When I open the index.html it's not how I expected it to be. It's just **simple html without any bootstrap***

### To do that you have to remove external files

bellow is link this is how you linl `CSS` *Cascading Style Sheets*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

bellow is script tag linking JavaScript, jQuery etc..

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Following is **pure html file no CSS, SCRIPT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>no external files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4"><h1>Test1</h1></div>
        <div class="span4"><h1>Test2</h1></div>
        <div class="span4"><h1>Test3</h1></div>
    </div>
    <p> Hi </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it's just pure HTML. But I realized that buttons work, but grids don't. Take a look at @neoLok 's post to see what I mean. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: what was your question first you can't change question when ever you need

Comment: @sanoj, I agree that it is frustrating if users change the meaning of their question after people have answered. However I can't see that this has happened here, unless there was a change to the post within the first five minutes (during which time changes do not count as separate edits). If you find that happening often, you can always wait for questions to settle down before answering - being the first to answer is not always a benefit.

Comment: (Incidentally, please don't flag problems in one question in comments for another, as that can be confusing - I have asked mods for that comment to be removed).

Comment: I am a little confused now... So how do I like put code into a comment when someone tells me what to correct and I try it but it still doesn't work?

Comment: @KevinN. i can't understand what you saying

Answer (score 0):

You have a script resource URL `jquery-2.1.3.webarchive` that has no file extension, presumably it should be `.js`

If that resource is not the jQuery library you would also need to include jQuery.js also, and before the other 2 scripts.

Use your browser console (F12) to look for files not loaded and for javascript errors thrown.

As a quick check you could load jQuery library from CDN using the following in place of `jquery-2.1.3.webarchive`

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you have to read question properly **It's just simple html without any bootstrap.**

Comment: @sanojlawrence That doesn't invalidate my answer

Comment: invalidate my answer  means *Bro am little weak in english*